# NullPointerException when calling addToRequestQueue

Tags: android, android-volley

I am working on post method with parameters. My app is not responding (find my code below). I am getting a `NullPointerException` when I am trying to add data into queue in `void addToRequestQueue(Request<T> req, String tag)`. Could you, please, help me to identify the problem.

**RegisterActivity**

```
public class RegistrationActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener, VolleyTasksListener {

private Button btnRegister;
private EditText edtEmail;
private EditText edtConfirmEmail;
private EditText edtPassword;
private EditText edtconfirmPassword;
private EditText edtFullName;
private EditText edtContactNumber;
private TextView txtDOB;
private LinearLayout parentLayout;
private Toolbar toolbar;
private String udid;
private TextView txtErrEmail;
private TextView txtErrCEMAIL;
private TextView txtErrPassword;
private TextView txtErrCpassword;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_register);

    findViews();
    initToolbar();
}

private void findViews() {

    parentLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.lyt_parent);
    btnRegister = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_register);
    txtDOB = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt_dob);
    txtErrPassword = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt_err_password);
    txtErrCpassword = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt_err_c_password);
    txtErrEmail = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt_err_email);
    txtErrCEMAIL = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt_err_c_email);

    edtEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edt_email);
    edtConfirmEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edt_confirm_email);
    edtPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edt_password);
    edtconfirmPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edt_confirm_password);
    edtFullName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edt_full_name);
    edtContactNumber = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edt_contact_number);
    udid = Settings.Secure.getString(RegistrationActivity.this.getContentResolver(), Settings.Secure.ANDROID_ID);

    TypefaceHelper.getInstance().setTypeface(parentLayout, Constant.FONT_OPENSANS_REGULAR);
    TypefaceHelper.getInstance().setTypeface(btnRegister, Constant.FONT_OPENSANS_BOLD);

    txtDOB.setOnClickListener(this);
    btnRegister.setOnClickListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    switch (view.getId()) {
        case R.id.btn_register:

            getRegistrationService();

            break;
        case R.id.txt_dob:
            ShowDatePicker();
            break;
    }

}


private void getRegistrationServiceValidation() {
    {
        String username = edtFullName.getText().toString().trim();
        String confirmEmail = edtConfirmEmail.getText().toString();
        String email = edtEmail.getText().toString();
        String confirmPassword = edtconfirmPassword.getText().toString();
        String mobile = edtContactNumber.getText().toString();
        String password = edtPassword.getText().toString();

        if (ValidationUtils.isValidEmail(email)) {
            if (ValidationUtils.isValidEmail(email, confirmEmail)) {
                if (ValidationUtils.isValidPassword(password)) {
                    if (ValidationUtils.isValidPassword(password, confirmPassword)) {

                        getRegistrationService();

                    } else {
                        txtErrCpassword.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        txtErrCpassword.setText("Password does not match");
                    }
                }else{
                    txtErrPassword.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    txtErrPassword.setText("Password require more than 8 character");
                }
            }else {
                txtErrCEMAIL.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                txtErrCEMAIL.setText("*Email does not match");
            }
        }else {
            txtErrEmail.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            txtErrEmail.setText("*This Email has already been used");
        }
    }
}


private void getRegistrationService() {

    if (ConnectionUtils.isConnectedNetwork(RegistrationActivity.this)) {
        JSONObject jsonMainObject = new JSONObject();
        try {
            jsonMainObject.put("email_id", edtEmail.getText().toString());
            jsonMainObject.put("password", edtPassword.getText().toString());
            jsonMainObject.put("full_name", edtFullName.getText().toString());
            jsonMainObject.put("contact_number", edtContactNumber.getText().toString());
            jsonMainObject.put("dob", txtDOB.getText().toString());
            jsonMainObject.put("gender", "Male");

            VolleyTasks.makeVolleyPost(RegistrationActivity.this, Constant.REGISTRATION_URL, jsonMainObject, "Login");

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } else {
        DialogUtils.switchOnInternetDialog(RegistrationActivity.this, false);
    }
}

private void getRegisterSucessAlert() {

    Builder builder = new Builder(this);
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    final View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.alet_register_success, (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.lnt_root));

    LinearLayout lytAlertParent = (LinearLayout) layout.findViewById(R.id.lnt_root);
    TextView txttitle = (TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.txt_register_title);
    TypefaceHelper.getInstance().setTypeface(lytAlertParent, Constant.FONT_OPENSANS_REGULAR);
    TypefaceHelper.getInstance().setTypeface(txttitle, Constant.FONT_OPENSANS_BOLD);

    Button btnOk = (Button) layout.findViewById(R.id.btn_ok);


    builder.setView(layout);
    final android.app.AlertDialog alertDialog = builder.create();
    alertDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true);
    alertDialog.show();

    btnOk.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            ActivityUtils.launchActivity(RegistrationActivity.this, HomeActivity.class, true);
        }
    });
}

private void ShowDatePicker() {
    {
        final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(RegistrationActivity.this, R.style.AppCompatAlertDialogStyle);
        final View view = View.inflate(RegistrationActivity.this, R.layout.picker_date, null);
        builder.setView(view);

        final DatePicker datePicker = (DatePicker) view.findViewById(R.id.date_picker);
        builder.setPositiveButton("Set", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                Calendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar(datePicker.getYear(), datePicker.getMonth(), datePicker.getDayOfMonth());
                String date = DateUtils.getSimpleDateFormat(Constant.DATE_TEMPLATE_CAB_BOOK, calendar.getTime());
                txtDOB.setText(date);
            }
        });
        builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                dialogInterface.dismiss();
            }
        });
        builder.show();
    }
}

private void initToolbar() {
    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    toolbar.setTitle("");
    toolbar.setTitleTextColor(Color.WHITE);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    ImageView imgClose = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img_close);
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        imgClose.setColorFilter(getResources().getColor(R.color.ft_blue, null));
    } else {
        imgClose.setColorFilter(getResources().getColor(R.color.ft_blue));
    }

    imgClose.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            ActivityUtils.launchActivity(RegistrationActivity.this, AuthenticationActivity.class, true);
        }
    });
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();
    ActivityUtils.launchActivity(this, AuthenticationActivity.class, true);
}

@Override
public void handleError(Exception error) {
    L.d("Error"+error);
}

@Override
public void handleResult(String method_name, JSONObject response) {
    L.d ("response" + response);
    if (response != null) {
        GsonBuilder gsonBuilder = new GsonBuilder();
        gsonBuilder.serializeNulls();
        Gson gson = gsonBuilder.create();
        if (method_name.equals("Login")) {
            AbstractRegister abstractRegister = gson.fromJson(response.toString(), AbstractRegister.class);
            if (abstractRegister != null) {
                if (abstractRegister.getResponse().equals("1")) {
                    getRegisterSucessAlert();
                } else {
                }
            } else {
            }
        }
    }

}}
```

**Application**

```
public class eTravelApplication extends Application {
private static eTravelApplication sInstance;
private RequestQueue mRequestQueue;
public static final String TAG = "VolleyPatterns";

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();

    TypefaceHelper.initialize(this);
}

/**
 * @return ApplicationController singleton instance
 */
public static synchronized eTravelApplication getInstance() {
    return sInstance;
}

public RequestQueue getRequestQueue() {
    // created when it is accessed for the first time
    if (mRequestQueue == null) {
        mRequestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue (getApplicationContext ());
    }

    return mRequestQueue;
}

/**
 * Adds the specified request to the global queue, if tag is specified
 * then it is used else Default TAG is used.
 *
 * @param req
 * @param tag
 */
public <T> void addToRequestQueue(Request<T> req, String tag) {
    // set the default tag if tag is empty
    req.setTag(TextUtils.isEmpty (tag) ? TAG : tag);

    VolleyLog.d ("Adding request to queue: %s", req.getUrl ());

    getRequestQueue().add(req);
}


public <T> void addToRequestQueue(Request<T> req) {
    // set the default tag if tag is empty
    req.setTag(TAG);

    getRequestQueue().add(req);
}

/**
 * Cancels all pending requests by the specified TAG, it is important
 * to specify a TAG so that the pending/ongoing requests can be cancelled.
 *
 * @param tag
 */
public void cancelPendingRequests(Object tag) {
    if (mRequestQueue != null) {
        mRequestQueue.cancelAll(tag);
    }
}



@Override
public void onTerminate() {
    TypefaceHelper.destroy();
    super.onTerminate();
}}
```